# How to parse quoted string with quotes in it

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get sql query (second parameter of FORM func)

`=FORM("onname", "SELECT "lname", "fname", "year" from table")`

I tried with:

```
.match(/^=FORM\("(.*)", *"((?:.|\n)*)"\)$/i)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = '=FORM("onname", "SELECT "lname", "fname", "year" from table")';
var sql = s.match(/^=FORM\("[^"]+", "(.+)"\)$/i)[1];
```

Comment: It works.I've modified your phrase to support new lines in SQL queries.

`.match(/^=FORM\("([^"]+)", "((?:.|\n)*)"\)$/i)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very specific to your problem solution:

`.replace(/=FORM\("[^"]+", "(.*)"\)/ig, "$1")`

[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qTGN2/)

Answer (score 0):

See it [in action](http://regexr.com?31uer):

```
^=FORM\(".*?",\s*"(.*)"\)$
```

Grab **1st capturing group** to use.